# How to create new table for the output of DISTINCT COUNT to be distributed in rows, not in column?

Tags: php, mysql, count, insert, distinct

My query displays the DISTINCT count of buyers with corresponding ticketserial#. I need to automatically calculate the SOLD and BALANCE column and save into the database either into the existing table (table1) with the rows that corresponds to the ticketserial. I've already exhausted my brain and did google many times but I just can't figure it out. So I tried another option by trying to create a new table into the database for the output of DISTINCT COUNT but I didn't find any sample query to follow, so that I could just use INNER JOIN for that new table with table1, with that the PRINTED, SOLD are in the same table, thus I can subtract these columns to obtain the values for the BALANCE column.
Existing table1 & table2 are records in the database via html form:

```
Table1
Ticket Serial     Printed Copies        SOLD(sold)        Balance
TS#1234                50           ?(should be auto        ?
TS#5678                80           ?(should be auto        ?
(so on and so forth...)

Table2
Buyer             Ticket Serial
Adam               TS#1234
Kathy              TS#1234
Sam                TS#5678
(so on and so forth...)
```

The COUNT DISTINCT outputs the qty. of sold tickets:

```
 <td> <?php print '<div align="center">'.$row['COUNT(ticketserial)'];?></td>
...
 $query = "SELECT *, COUNT(ticketserial) FROM buyers WHERE ticketsold != 'blank' GROUP BY 
 ticketserial ";
```

It's COUNT output looks like this:

```
Ticket Serial------Distinct Count
TS#1234                     7
TS#5678                     25
(so on and so forth...)
```

I tried to update the SOLD column and BALANCE column by UPDATE or INSERT and foreach loop **but only the first row in table was updated**.

```
Table1
Ticket Serial     Printed Copies   Sold    Balance
TS#1234                50         **7**         0
TS#5678                80         **0**         0
TS#8911                40         **0**         0
(so on and so forth...)
```

Note: The fieldname "sold" in table1 is not the same with the fieldname "ticketsold" in table2 as the former is quantity and the later is ticketserials.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to follow. However this looks like a `left join` on a aggregate query:

```
select
    t1.ticket_serial,
    t1.printed_copies,
    coalesce(t2.sold, 0) sold,
    t1.printed_copies - coalesce(t2.sold, 0) balance
from table1 t1
left join (
    select ticket_serial, count(*) sold 
    from table2 
    group by ticket_serial
) t2 on t2.ticket_serial = t1.ticket_serial
```

If you are looking to `update` the main table:

```
update table1 t1
left join (
    select ticket_serial, count(*) sold 
    from table2 
    group by ticket_serial
) t2 on t2.ticket_serial = t1.ticket_serial 
set 
    t1.sold = coalesce(t2.sold, 0),
    t1.balance = t1.printed_copies - coalesce(t2.sold, 0)
```

I would not actually recommend storing the `sold` and `balance` in the main table - this is derived information that can be easily computed when needed, and would be tedious to maintain. If needed, you could create a view using the first above SQL statement, which will give you an always up-to-date perspective at your data.

Comment: Congrats on hitting 100k!

Comment: i'm just a newbie, and I just want to know, referring to your line of code ..."left join (
    select ticket_serial, count(*) sold" ... if you considered the premise that table t2 has no SOLD column as it only outputs the COUNT of occurrence of ticket_serial which I also labeled (table heading) as SOLD. I mean to say, the output of COUNT cannot be found in database. So my question is, are you referring the word "SOLD" as the fieldname of table t1 for the sold variables since there is no sold fieldname in t2 in the database?

Comment: @mnunez: that's an alias for `count(*)`

Comment: based on your suggestion, i made this query but it doesn't update table1:  $query ="UPDATE table1 t1 left join (SELECT ticket_serial, COUNT(*) sold  from table2 
    group by ticket_serial) t2 on t2.ticket_serial = t1.ticket_serial SET t1.sold = coalesce(t2.sold, 0),  t1.balance = t1.printed_copies - coalesce(t2.sold, 0)";$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,  MYSQLI_BOTH);
echo $row
?>